# regex replace only the first occurrence of every match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I replace only the first occurrence of every match?

Example.

The following string

```
var toReplace='href="/3" href="/3/a" href="a/3" href="h/3/a/3/b"'
```

after replace should be like:

```
'href="*" href="*/a" href="*" href="*/a/3/b"'
```

I use this regex

```
toReplace.replace(/(href=")[^"]*(\/3)/,'$1*')
```

but the result is this:

```
'href="*" href="*/a"  href="*" href="*/b" '
```

The last href in that case becomes `href="*/b" instead of href="*/a/3/b"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^"]*` will try to match all possible matches.

Use non-greedy/lazy regex

```
/(href=")[^"]*?(\/3)/
              ^
              |
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hI4cE4/1)

```js
var toReplace = 'href="/3" href="/3/a" href="a/3" href="h/3/a/3/b"';
var replacedString = toReplace.replace(/(href=")[^"]*?(\/3)/gi, '$1*');

document.write(replacedString);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was so close!

Comment: @MikeAntoniadis Welcome! Glad to help.